# How do I make WIF use RSA15 when encrypting data using a certificate?

Tags: wcf, wif

I have been working on a WCF service which will return a Base64 encoded string which is, in reality, a full SAML response XML document.  Because this information will be handed off to a vendor, I have to meet their requirements for how the SAML document will look and be encoded.  I am having trouble getting an output which meets their requirements.

I know WCF and WIF together should help me.  I originally built the service using WIF to create the SAML Assertions (token) and other C# code to generate the final SAML document.  All of this works and meets the vendor's requirements except for the <EncryptedData> node of the document.  This section uses AES256 and RSAOAEP but the vendor wants AES128 and RSA15.  Thus, I am hunting for a resolution.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a walk through.

The service takes in a GUID which is used to call the database and return fields.  These are then used like so:

```
DataTable userData = GetDataForUser(userId);
List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>()
{
    new Claim("ClientId", "NameOfClient")
};
foreach (DataRow row in userData.Rows)
{
    string memberId = row["MemberId"].ToString().Trim();
    string firstName = row["FirstName"].ToString().Trim();
    string lastName = row["LastName"].ToString().Trim();
    DateTime dob = Convert.ToDateTime(row["DateOfBirth"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    claims.Add(new Claim("MemberId", memberId));
    claims.Add(new Claim("FirstName", firstName));
    claims.Add(new Claim("LastName", lastName));
    claims.Add(new Claim("DOB", dob.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")));
}

return claims;
```

I then create a SecurityTokenDescriptor like this:

```
SecurityTokenDescriptor descriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor();
```

The claims are added to the descriptor like so:

```
descriptor.Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
```

The descriptor is instructed to encrypt the token like this:

```
descriptor.EncryptingCredentials = GetEncryptingCredentials();
```

and the GetEncryptingCredentials() routine looks like this:

```
private EncryptedKeyEncryptingCredentials GetEncryptingCredentials()
{
    // Get the Encrypting Certificate
    X509Certificate2 encryptCert = CertificateHelper.FindSingleCertificate(StoreName.TrustedPeople, StoreLocation.LocalMachine, X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, "<<certificate stuff here >>", true);

    EncryptedKeyEncryptingCredentials encryptingCreds = new EncryptedKeyEncryptingCredentials(encryptCert);

    return encryptingCreds;
 }
```

All of this generates a token which, when written to a file gives me this:

```
  <EncryptedAssertion xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
    <xenc:EncryptedData Id="_16584ace-9f3e-4352-9fc9-f6db8b2e925c" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
      <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" />
      <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <e:EncryptedKey xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
          <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p">
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
          </e:EncryptionMethod>
          <KeyInfo>
            <o:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
              <X509Data>
                <X509IssuerSerial>
                  <X509IssuerName><!-- value --></X509IssuerName>
                  <X509SerialNumber><!-- value --></X509SerialNumber>
                </X509IssuerSerial>
              </X509Data>
            </o:SecurityTokenReference>
          </KeyInfo>
          <e:CipherData>
            <e:CipherValue><!-- value -->CipherValue>
          </e:CipherData>
        </e:EncryptedKey>
      </KeyInfo>
      <xenc:CipherData><xenc:CipherValue><!-- value --></xenc:CipherValue>
      </xenc:CipherData>
    </xenc:EncryptedData>
  </EncryptedAssertion>
```

Great, right?  Nope.  The vendor needs the <EncryptedData> section to have the following child node:

```
<EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"/>
```

And they need the <KeyInfo><EncryptedKey> section to show this:

```
<EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"/>
```

I have tried every combination I can think of within the GetEncryptingCredentials() routine.  Nothing has produced the desired results.  The most promising error message I receive looks like this:

> ID4178: The EncryptingCredentials
>   provided in the
>   SecurityTokenDescriptor is for an
>   asymmetric key. You must use an
>   EncryptedKeyEncryptingCredentials to
>   encrypt the token.

Anyone have a suggestion?  Don't be afraid to tell me to start all over.  That's all right.  I just need to get this to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution which works.  At least, it generates the XML as I need it to and the vendor has said they are able to use what I am sending them.

I rewrote the GetEncryptingCredentials() routine slightly.  It now looks like this:

```
private EncryptingCredentials GetEncryptingCredentials()
{
    string keyWrapAlgorithm = SecurityAlgorithms.RsaV15KeyWrap; //"http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc";
    string encryptionAlgorithm = SecurityAlgorithms.Aes128Encryption; //"http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p";
    int keySize = 128;

    X509Certificate2 encryptCert = CertificateHelper.FindSingleCertificate(StoreName.TrustedPeople, StoreLocation.LocalMachine, X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, _settings.EncryptingCredentials, true);

    EncryptingCredentials encryptingCredentials = new EncryptedKeyEncryptingCredentials(encryptCert, keyWrapAlgorithm, keySize, encryptionAlgorithm);

    return encryptingCredentials;
}
```

Just thought I would let everyone know and close the loop on this.

Comment: You rock man, I've been looking for information on how to get working properly!

Comment: This post is very old, not sure if you'll remember any of it! Haha! But shouldn't the X509Data section under KeyInfo include the X509Certificate as well?