# Where did the WIF SecurityAlgorithms class go?

Tags: .net-4.0, wif

I was reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4204796/285951) and trying to copy the method used there, but VS2010 and the compiler refuse to acknowledge that SecurityAlgorithms exists as part of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens, even though [MSDN says it does](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.securityalgorithms.aspx). I am getting the error: "The type or namespace name 'SecurityAlgorithms' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

I installed WIF from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17331) (Windows6.1-KB974405-x64.msu) and the WIF SDK from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=4451) (WindowsIdentityFoundation-SDK-4.0.msi). Then I added 
a reference to Microsoft.IdentityModel to my project.

Is there something I have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, it is actually in System.IdentityModel.Tokens, not Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.